# Potential tag synonyms: flavor, flavour, coffee-taste

Tags: discussion, status-completed

There is currently one question tagged with [flavour](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavour), and several others taged with [flavor](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavor). There is also a tag [coffee-taste](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coffee-taste). Since I doubt anyone has enough rep to create a synonym yet, I made this meta post.

These could potentially all be merged.

What should be used? Can a SE person please unify the questions / make synonyms? Are there any other variations of this already in use that should also be merged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I merged the [flavor](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavor) and [taste](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taste) tags and and created a synonym mapping from [taste](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taste) → [flavor](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavor).

When it comes to regional spelling variations, we've standardized on the US variant. There's no need to create a synonym for [flavour](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavour) because the text completion will suggest the correct tag.